# My select box give me the wrong value. How to do foreach in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have a select box in my form. The select box is for a list of the available driver at that time. I only have 2 drivers and all the driver are booked. But when I make a driver reservation, there is 1 driver show on the list. I think I have a mistakes in my foreach. Am I right? Do you know how to fix that?
This below is my controller code:

```
    $driverReserved = Reservation::select("RES_DRIVER")->where("RES_RETURN", '>', $reservation[0]->RES_DEPARTURE)->where('RES_STATUS', '=', 'Assigned')->Where('RES_SPK', '!=', $request['RES_SPK'])->exists();

    $driverReserved1 = Reservation::select("RES_DRIVER")->where("RES_RETURN", '>', $reservation[0]->RES_DEPARTURE)->where('RES_STATUS', '=', 'Assigned')->Where('RES_SPK', '!=', $request['RES_SPK'])->distinct()->get();

    if(empty($driverReserved)){
        $driver = vDriver::all();
    }
    else{
        foreach($driverReserved1 as $item1) {
            $driver = vDriver::where("REF_TEXT", "!=", $item1['RES_DRIVER'])->get();
        }

    }
```

And this is when I do the `print_r($dirverReserved1);die;` . There is 2 driver in it.

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Reservation Object ( [timestamps] => [primaryKey:protected] => RES_ID [table:protected] => RESERVATION [connection:protected] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [RES_DRIVER] => Asim ) [original:protected] => Array ( [RES_DRIVER] => Asim ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => ) [1] => App\Reservation Object ( [timestamps] => [primaryKey:protected] => RES_ID [table:protected] => RESERVATION [connection:protected] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [RES_DRIVER] => Sulhi Mukhlas ) [original:protected] => Array ( [RES_DRIVER] => Sulhi Mukhlas ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => ) ) )

But when I do `print_r($item1['RES_DRIVER']);die;` inside the foreach, it's only show 1 driver named Asim.

Comment: why are you using **Where** instead of **where** in the query ? And another thing is `->exists()` will return boolean value true or false but in if statement you have checked boolean value as empty or not, why ?

Comment: because I only can show the booked driver on my query $driverReserved1, so I have to select the name of the driver who are not on $driverReserved1 result.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do, can you explain please.

Comment: my $driverReserved is for checking if there is a booked driver exist or not. if not exist then i show all the driver name. if exist, I select the booked driver name in $driverReserved1 then I select the driver who are not on that list in $driver. I know my code is mess, but I have tried my best. when I checked with boolean value in my exist, it's not working (or maybe i made a mistake) but with the empty its working.

Comment: I've understand little bit Can you explain what are REF_TEXT and RES_DRIVER

Comment: RES_DRIVER is the name of booked driver in the reservation table. and REF_TEXT is the name of the driver in the driver table

Comment: I've just added my answer to your problem take a moment to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using name of the driver for handling all these things but if you have used **ID** then it would better.

Anyway,

I think you should use `pluck` and `whereNotIn` in your code to get out of the problem like this,

Change your query for `$driverReserved1` as,

```
$driverReserved1 = Reservation::select("RES_DRIVER")->where("RES_RETURN", '>', $reservation[0]->RES_DEPARTURE)->where('RES_STATUS', '=', 'Assigned')->Where('RES_SPK', '!=', $request['RES_SPK'])->distinct()->pluck('RES_DRIVER');
```

This will give you array of distinct driver name which are reserved. Now, using `whereNotIn` you can get drivers other than booked driver like this,

```
if(empty($driverReserved)){
    $driver = vDriver::all();
}
else{
        $driver = vDriver::whereNotIn("REF_TEXT",$driverReserved1)->get();
}
```

I think this will work for your case.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

First Check [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections) it has pretty good functions

Second you the code is right and the output is right too :D

you just expected wrong output

```
    foreach($driverReserved1 as $item1) {
        $driver = vDriver::where("REF_TEXT", "!=", $item1['RES_DRIVER'])->get();
    }
```

here you just said last record will be saved in $driver so you need them all in driver you may use

array_merge($firstArray,$secondArray);

in your example here it will be like

```
foreach($driverReserved1 as $item1) {
        $driver = array_merge($driver ,vDriver::where("REF_TEXT", "!=", $item1['RES_DRIVER'])->get());
    }
```

and of course assigning driver before